# 01 ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `bin/rails credentials:edit`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, capistrano

After copying the newly created master.key file from my dev server to the prod server, and running

```
cap production deploy
```

I get this error message:

```
00:13 deploy:assets:precompile
  01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile
  01 rake aborted!
  01 ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `bin/rails credentials:edit`
```

What is the next best steps on troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 2):

Set the key secret_key_base for the production environment. This key should already be set for the development environment. You need to set it for the production environment as well. You can do this by running the command `bin/rails credentials:edit`.

```
    production:
      secret_key_base: '<SECRET_KEY_VALUE>'
```

Comment: Where do you run this? If Capistrano has never deployed, `bin/rails` doesn't exist on the server yet.